# PHP and DST conversion issue

Tags: php, timezone, dst

I'm having trouble understanding how my code adapts to DST, as it's incorrect with the recent update. I'm storing a date time in the database based on UTC and then converting it back to the local timezone for display. If PHP is taking DST into account, something else is wrong because all of my stored dates are 1 hour off.

```
$stored_date = '2016-11-16 12:04:01'; // in UTC

$dateTime = new DateTime($stored_date, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$dateTimeZone = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');
$dateTime->setTimezone($dateTimeZone);

print_r($dateTime);
```

Last week, before DST ended, this would have printed out 2016-11-16 08:04:01. This week, now that DST has ended, it prints out 2016-11-16 07:04:01. Why the hour difference if PHP is properly handing the DST shift?

It shouldn't matter the server settings (I don't think) because I'm explicitly doing the conversion within PHP, right?

I'm ready to start doing a check with PHP to see if DST is in effect and offsetting the conversion by 1 hour because I can't figure out why that hour isn't being automatically compensated for within the DateTime class.

Comment: Doesn't that hour difference represent the change in DST which is what you would expect? I'm not sure what you're expecting to be different.

Comment: The result should be 2016-11-16 08:04:01 regardless of whether or not DST is in effect. I'm assuming that when PHP converts from UTC to another timezone, it would know if DST is in effect and produce the same local time. Maybe the answer is that PHP is technically doing the right thing and I need to compensate for my business case by adjusting for DST.

Comment: That date is *after* DST changes so it should never be 2016-11-16 08:04:01. Dates before DST changes should be 08:04:01 but not after.

Comment: Got it, that makes sense.

Comment: We "fall back" in November, so what would be `08:04:01` before the time change is supposed to be `07:04:01` after. `Americas/New York` changes from -4 to -5. I see no problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New York city switches between these time zones:

- Winter: [EST](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/est) (Eastern Standard Time) = UTC -5
- Summer: [EDT](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/edt) (Eastern Daylight Time) = UTC -4

According to [timeanddate.com](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/new-york) the switch will happen on 6th of November. Thus the result is correct: `12 - 5 = 7`

In other words, PHP is perfectly aware of DST, as we can see in the following code:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime('2016-11-05 12:04:01', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$dateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
echo $dateTime->format('r') . PHP_EOL;

$dateTime = new DateTime('2016-11-06 12:04:01', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$dateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
echo $dateTime->format('r') . PHP_EOL;
```

```
Sat, 05 Nov 2016 08:04:01 -0400
Sun, 06 Nov 2016 07:04:01 -0500
```

You can inspect the exact information available in your system's time database:

```
$timeZone = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');
print_r($timeZone->getTransitions(mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2016), mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 31, 2016)));
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ts] => 1451602800
            [time] => 2015-12-31T23:00:00+0000
            [offset] => -18000
            [isdst] => 
            [abbr] => EST
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ts] => 1457852400
            [time] => 2016-03-13T07:00:00+0000
            [offset] => -14400
            [isdst] => 1
            [abbr] => EDT
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ts] => 1478412000
            [time] => 2016-11-06T06:00:00+0000
            [offset] => -18000
            [isdst] => 
            [abbr] => EST
        )

)
```